# Merge elements when exporting to XML

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, excel-2010

I'm trying to export a table in Excel to an XML file. I created a schema but I don’t have exactly the result I expect. Here is a simple example of my table: [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN5cL.jpg).

[image]

My schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
             <xs:element name="Group" type="groupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="groupType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="City" type="cityType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" />
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cityType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" />
</xs:complexType>
```

This is the result I get when I export to XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<list>
    <Group name="groupA">
        <City name="Dublin">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupA">
        <City name="Prague">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupA">
        <City name="Sofia">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupA">
        <City name="Tunis">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupB">
        <City name="Paris">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupB">
        <City name="Lisbon">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupB">
        <City name="Madrid">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
</list>
```

It's not bad, but I would like to merge the rows which have the same group name (groupA and groupB) in the same node. In other terms, I would like to have this result:

```
<list>
    <Group name="groupA">
        <City name="Dublin">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
        <City name="Prague">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
        <City name="Sofia">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
        <City name="Tunis">
            <value>yes</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
    <Group name="groupB">
        <City name="Paris">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
        <City name="Lisbon">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
        <City name="Madrid">
            <value>no</value>
        </City>
    </Group>
</list>
```

What should I do in my schema to make the result like I want?

Comment: Excel is only able directly exporting XML in table form. This is a sequence of data rows (records) in which each data field has exactly one element. In your case this is a sequence of Groups in which each group has exactly one City with one value. This is what you get already. What you want is a sequence of Groups, each with a sequence of Cities. This is not possible directly with the Excel XML export. Either you use VBA for this or you take what you have and transform this using XSLT outside Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is only able directly exporting XML in table form. This is a sequence of data rows (records) in which each data field has exactly one element. It is not able exporting list of lists. That is: One list of items has a second list of items. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-XML-data-0b21f51b-56d6-48f0-83d9-a89637cd4360.

But you want list of lists.  A sequence of Groups, each with a sequence of Cities. The schema would be:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Group" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="City" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But as documented this can't be exported directly with Excel's XML export feature.

So I suggest using VBA for this. The following will create the needed XML from the shown data.

```
Sub testXLStoXML()

 Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 Set oPI = oXMLDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""")
 Set oRoot = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "list", "")
 oXMLDoc.appendChild oRoot
 oXMLDoc.InsertBefore oPI, oXMLDoc.ChildNodes.Item(0)

 With ActiveSheet

  lRow = 2
  sGroupName = ""

  Do While .Cells(lRow, 1).Value <> ""

   sGroupName = .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
   Set oElmGroup = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Group", "")
   oXMLDoc.DocumentElement.appendChild oElmGroup
   Set oAttr = oXMLDoc.createNode(2, "name", "")
   oAttr.NodeValue = sGroupName
   oElmGroup.setAttributeNode oAttr

   Do While .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = sGroupName

    Set oElmCity = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "City", "")
    Set oAttr = oXMLDoc.createNode(2, "name", "")
    oAttr.NodeValue = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
    oElmCity.setAttributeNode oAttr

    Set oElmValue = oXMLDoc.createNode(1, "Value", "")
    oElmValue.appendChild oXMLDoc.createTextNode(.Cells(lRow, 3).Value)

    oElmCity.appendChild oElmValue
    oElmGroup.appendChild oElmCity

    lRow = lRow + 1

   Loop

  Loop

 End With

 MsgBox oXMLDoc.XML

 oXMLDoc.Save "test.xml"

End Sub
```

The Worksheet with the shown data must be the active worksheet while the macro is running.