# unable to export xml file from excel using xsd file?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

This is my excel file

[image]

and here is my xsd file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element name="Root">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="ID" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="Numbers" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                    <element name="Numbers" type="string"/>
                  </sequence>
                </complexType>
              </element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="ID" type="string"/>
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

I want XML file like this:

```
<Data>
<ID>1</ID>
    <Number>21</Number>
    <Number>23</Number>
    <Number>22</Number>
</Data>
<Data>
<ID>2</ID>
    <Number>24</Number>
    <Number>25</Number> 
</Data>
<Data>
<ID>3</ID>
    <Number>26</Number>
    <Number>26</Number> 
</Data>
```

But while using this schema, I am able to map but unable to export the file. I am able to map the schema with the columns (ID, Number) using excel developer mode but when I try to export, it gives error that cannot create xml file. I am new to xml thing, may be I am doing something wrong with xsd file.

I need the file like for id 1 there must be 3 child having 21,23 and 22. Then for id 2, two child i.e. 24 and 25. Same for id 3.

Getting this error:

[image]

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: I think more clarity is required. Where do you want to export the file. What are you doing ? This might help others to answer your question.

Comment: @Junail Suirwani I just need to generate the xml file. Data is in excel, i have to make a xml schema so that I can generate the desired xml file.

Comment: So what are you using right now? Do you have code that you have tried to write

Comment: I added the xsd file above which I am working on and using developer mode in excel i am mapping, but unable to export the xml.

Comment: Excel is not able exporting list of lists in XML this way. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707220/merge-elements-when-exporting-to-xml/33709120#33709120