# Why does Excel 2010 not let me use embedded elements when exporting to XML

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I am trying to have excel output a specific xml format which has an element embedded in another element. See Below. However, excel will only allow me to export as xml. I am able to export as xml if I do not embebbed the Process element in the Formula element but I need them embedded for communication with the end software. Below is the xml I need to output and the xsd I am inputting. Is there something I am missing?

XML Ouput Needed:

```
<Formula>
<Name>My Formula</Name>
<Process>                             
  <Ing>90000001</Ing>        
  <ReqAmount>14</ReqAmount>                               
</ProcessInput>
<Process>
  <Ing>90000002</Ing>
  <ReqAmount>5</ReqAmount>
</Process> </Formula>
```

The Process block needs to have unbounded repetitions

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Formula">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name = "Process" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Ing" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="ReqAmount" type="xs:double"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>  
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error I get is "Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable. "

Thanks!

Comment: Why the `xs:choice` is needed? Your XSD states that a `Formula` should contain either a `Name` or a list of `Process`. But in your "XML Ouput Needed" the `Formula` contains both. So why the `choice`?. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-XML-data-0b21f51b-56d6-48f0-83d9-a89637cd4360 - scroll down to "The XML Maps in your workbook can't be exported".

Comment: I was just trying different compositors to see if it would work. I also tried with sequence and I was unable export.

Comment: In the link you gave Axel there is a statement "List of lists    One list of items has a second list of items." Does that mean excel doesn't have this capability? I was referencing this https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-tutorial/xsd-elements-attributes for my xsd structure. See Compositors section.

Comment: I was only curious about reason of the usage of `choice`. But no, `Excel` will not be able to export this kind of XML either because "List of lists" if your Formula element would consists of multiple Names too or because "Denormalized data" if there is only one Name but a list of Process. First question always: How would the XML data be shown in a 2 dimensional structure as the spreadsheet is? You could using VBA to export the XML. There you are free taking the spreadsheet data to the XML structure in any kind you want.

Comment: Ok. So yes, the Formula block is meant to have one Name and a list of processes. So you are saying excel can't do that? Should I just make a UI using something else?

Comment: Or would VBA allow me to have my desired set up? If so how do I go about that.

Comment: I am currently uploading a Source mapping in xsd, mapping it to the columns and then exporting.

Comment: As said: How would you show the XML data in the 2 dimensional spreadsheet  structure? If this is clear, then VBA gives you all the free you wants. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707220/merge-elements-when-exporting-to-xml/33709120#33709120 for an example.

Comment: Thank you! I am able to code with VBA and create my desired encapsulation. One question. I am using createTextNode to create string nodes. How do I create Nodes of other Data Types? When I use this on numbers it add a 1 after all my numbers.

Comment: This is not to answer from a comment. Please ask another question. Provide the code you are currently using and example data in the sheet and describe the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Excel sheet should really only containing one formula, then the following would work:

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Formula">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
        <xs:element name="Process" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Ing"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ReqAmount"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Excel:

[image]

As you see, the field `Name` had been dragged to `A1` and the `Process` had been dragged to `A2`.

This is exportable and leads to the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Formula>
    <Name>MyFormula</Name>
    <Process>
        <Ing>90000001</Ing>
        <ReqAmount>14</ReqAmount>
    </Process>
    <Process>
        <Ing>90000002</Ing>
        <ReqAmount>5</ReqAmount>
    </Process>
    <Process>
        <Ing>90000003</Ing>
        <ReqAmount>123</ReqAmount>
    </Process>
    <Process>
        <Ing>90000004</Ing>
        <ReqAmount>456</ReqAmount>
    </Process>
</Formula>
```

Comment: When I add it to my other code it doesn't work.. not sure because when I comment out this part it works. I just coded it from scratch in VBA.  I am using createTextNode to create string nodes. How do I create Nodes of other Data Types? When I use this on numbers it add a 1 after all my numbers

Comment: I just followed your advice stated here "  
As said: How would you show the XML data in the 2 dimensional spreadsheet structure? If this is clear, then VBA gives you all the free you wants. See stackoverflow.com/questions/33707220/… for an example. – Axel Richter 4 hours ago " and coded it in VBA

Comment: Is there a similar createTextNode method for double data type?